# Including ffmpeg in C program

Tags: c, macos, ffmpeg, osx-yosemite

I'm using dranger's ffmpeg tutorial:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

I'm stuck trying to compile the first tutorial. I downloaded ffmpeg using homebrew, but the compile command provided in the tutorial did not work:

`gcc -o tutorial01 tutorial01.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm`

Based on my experience with SDL, I made a separate file that simply included one of the ffmpeg headers, and changed the compile command to:

`gcc main.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1/include`

It was actually able to compile. But when I tried this with the tutorial file using this command:

`gcc tutorial01.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1/include`

I got these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_av_dump_format", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_frame_alloc", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_frame_free", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_free", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_free_packet", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_malloc", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_read_frame", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_av_register_all", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_alloc_context3", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_close", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_copy_context", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_decode_video2", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_find_decoder", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avcodec_open2", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avformat_close_input", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avformat_find_stream_info", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avformat_open_input", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avpicture_fill", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_avpicture_get_size", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_sws_getContext", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
  "_sws_scale", referenced from:
      _main in tutorial01-9cd32b.o
```

I figured I had to add the extra things from the tutorial, so I did

`gcc tutorial01.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1/include -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm`

But then I got this error

```
ld: library not found for -lavutil
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I feel like the directory `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.1/lib` might be relevant, it includes the files:

```
libavcodec.56.26.100.dylib  libavresample.dylib
libavcodec.56.dylib         libavutil.54.20.100.dylib
libavcodec.a                libavutil.54.dylib
libavcodec.dylib            libavutil.a
libavdevice.56.4.100.dylib  libavutil.dylib
libavdevice.56.dylib        libpostproc.53.3.100.dylib
libavdevice.a               libpostproc.53.dylib
libavdevice.dylib           libpostproc.a
libavfilter.5.11.102.dylib  libpostproc.dylib
libavfilter.5.dylib         libswresample.1.1.100.dylib
libavfilter.a               libswresample.1.dylib
libavfilter.dylib           libswresample.a
libavformat.56.25.101.dylib libswresample.dylib
libavformat.56.dylib        libswscale.3.1.101.dylib
libavformat.a               libswscale.3.dylib
libavformat.dylib           libswscale.a
libavresample.2.1.0.dylib   libswscale.dylib
libavresample.2.dylib       pkgconfig
libavresample.a
```

I'm often really lost trying to compile downloaded libraries (it took me a long time to get SDL to compile, and when I finally got it to work I still didn't completely understand why).

If anyone could help me understand how these things work, and specifically help me compile this first tutorial, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav* may list some more updated tutorials, GL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg seems to use pkgconfig. So maybe u take a look how to use it.

http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html

In short:

```
cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs x` -o myapp myapp.c
```

is the thing u must add to your compiler invocation. Where x is the library name (like ffmpeg)

Comment: I'm not sure what I should put as x, but I tried `gcc \`pkg-config --cflags --libs libavutil\` tutorial01.c -o a.out`. I got the error `/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found`.

It's my understanding that the library has an "x.pc" file, which I located at `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc`.

Comment: Yes, u did it correct. The error u get is that pkgconfig is not installed on your computer. Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah, that's the case. After I installed It (and made a few other changes) it worked! I had to change `lavutil lavformat lavcodec` to `libavutil libaavformat libavcodec` and I had to replace `-lz -lm` with `libswscale`, but it compiled. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.